# how to display map using mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

**AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.java**

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
    import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

    public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Displaying Zooming controls
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    /**
     * Changing Map Type
     * */
    mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
    // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
    // mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

    /**
     * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
     * */        
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("48.85827758964043");
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("2.294543981552124");
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    // Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+(lat * 1E6)+","+(lon * 1E6));
    /* Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+(geoPoint));

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
    //intent.setPackage(defaultGpsPackage);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);*/
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate(); 


    /**
     * Placing Marker
     * */
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
         new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Hello", "Sample Overlay item");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

   }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
    }
```

**AddItemizedOverlay.java**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

    public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

private Context context;

public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
this(defaultMarker);
this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
return mapOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
return mapOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
Log.e("Tap", "Tap Performed");
return true;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);
this.populate();
}
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   

    if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
    GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
    (int) event.getX(),
    (int) event.getY());
    // latitude
    double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
    // longitude
    double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
    Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                            
    return false;
    } 

}
```

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCgSK8QeqICTwIYuxkx2TAixqjePsaf01o"
    />
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity" >
    <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>   

    </manifest>
```

i need to display the map.But using this code am getting only the grid view and latitude and longitude value.can anyone  please tell me what correction i should make here to display the map using mapview

Comment: what exactly is your error???

Comment: Logcat Error:04-21 16:55:16.728: E/MapActivity(1166): Couldn't get connection factory client.(am getting only grid view not map).

Answer (score 0):

**Do you know the [GoogleMapV1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/) is already depricated?**

From Docs:

> **Note:** Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

So you will no longer be able to use the GoogleMapV1 to use the map. You must have to switch to the [GoogleMapV2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) and implement it to load your map.

Comment: Am using Google Map V2 Only.I dont get Map View.Only grid is displaying with lat and long value

Comment: Your code clearly shows you are using `GoogleMapV1`. It will only show the grid because you are no longer can request for the map key and to load the map you need to get map api key which is now no more can be requested.

Comment: i got an api key and i gave it in xml file.look that

Comment: Though you have given the api key still it will not work. Have you read the documentation of `GoogleMapV1`?

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) as it provides a good tutorial to implement google maps v2..

Here is the complete code to show google maps v2..

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.movingmarkergooglemaps.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.movingmarkergooglemaps;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

GoogleMap Mmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

    }
    gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    Mmap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.movingmarkergooglemaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="**Replace with your key**" />
</application>
```

**Dont forget add google-play-services_lib**

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my java class and xml. Simply load it into your project. Hope it works for you. I spent lot of time to find this exact solution.

**java File:**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private TextView lblLocation;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location_on_map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.idLocationMap);
        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idLocationText);
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        Log.d("location is : ", gpsTracker.getLatitude() + " and " + gpsTracker.getLongitude());
        lblLocation.setText(gpsTracker.getAddressLine(MapActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        //LatLng class is google provided class to get latiude and longitude of location.
        //GpsTracker is helper class to get the details for current location latitude and longitude.
        LatLng location = new LatLng(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude());
        map = googleMap;
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker position"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
```

}

**Xml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idLocationText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Location: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/idLocationMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        map:liteMode="true"
        map:mapType="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```